# Can I run PowerShell scripts in an Silverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, powershell

Can I run PowerShell scripts in an Silverlight application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverlight is sandboxed, so even if you should manage to include PowerShell in your project, it would only run within your sandbox. However, you'll need the source to compile PowerShell to a Silverlight DLL

Cheers

```
Nik
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so... you would need the Process class, which is not available in Silverlight (for obvious security reasons...)

Answer (score 0):

There are PowerShell .net providers for sale now that could allow for what you need.